# In Unity3d, a child object with Skinned Mesh Renderer suddely starts to far behind from the parent object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm deving a 3D infinite runner (like Subway Surfer) and got this really weird glitch.

There's a 'Player Character Object' which has all the rigidbody, boxcollider, controller script components and there's a child object that only has 'skinned mesh renderer'.

Sometimes the 'Parent Object(that has all the components)' and the 'Child Object(only has skinned mesh renderer)' have different World Position ONLY IN THE SCENE VIEW (the child object's local position is 0,0,0 when this happen) and starts to make 'ghost collide (trigger things that are far from the parent object's world position)'.

It's weird because the parent object's Transform.position value is 'RIGHT' in inspector but in the SCENE VIEW, it's FAR AHEAD from the child object and make the 'ghost collide'. The Main Camera follows the 'child object' (which is the RIGHT position accord to the Parent.Transform.position value).

What makes it weirder is that, the child object slowly catch up the parent object and stop follow when it finally catches the parent object. (The Transform.position value doesn't change. The 'catch up thing' only happens in the SCENE VIEW.)

What would be the most common reason cause this kind glitch?

(Ad Info : I'm using URP Unlit/Curved shader.)

Comment: I'd need to see video or something of what you're talking about, but it's entirely possible that your whole player character object is with the child object. I've seen behavior similar to what you're describing before, but the entire physics object is what's lagging, which would be the player character object. It might look like only the child GameObject is lagging because the child GO is what has the visible thing on it, but it's all lagging. This was usually the case for me when I had joints with a large mass difference on the root and connected anchor of the joint.

Comment: @Chuck I just found out that this happen when I ZOOM IN THE SCENE VIEW(view only small amount of the entire world). It never happen when I ZOOM OUT THE SCENE VIEW. It happens a lot when Maximize On Play. What sorcery is this!

Comment: Sounds weird. Having a hard time imagining it.

Comment: @Chuck Maybe I should consult a priest not engineers. This is black voodoo magic. There's no scientifically legit explanation to this phenomenon.

Comment: @Chuck I can't really 'Record the phenomenon' because I've tried to 'catch the moment of separation' but it NEVER happen when I observe the entire objects in Scene View. It only happens when I CAN NOT SEE THE MOMENT IT HAPPENS(in Scene View).